# How to avoid GOTO in this code

Tags: c, goto

This is a derivate of C, so please don't get all angry that it doesn't look correct. It is indeed correct in this implementation.

I have this code:

```
func() {
    if (handler_1()) goto good;
    if (handler_2()) goto good;
    if (handler_3()) goto good;

    print("BAD");
    goto done;

good:
    print("GOOD");
    goto done;

done:
    print("DONE");
    // do some common stuff
}
```

I am not particularly happy with the gotos and labels, so I tried to use a do-while instead, but one GOTO is still left.

```
func() {
    do {
        if (handler_1()) break;
        if (handler_2()) break;
        if (handler_3()) break;

        print("BAD");
        goto done;
    } while(false);

    print("GOOD");

done:
    print("DONE");
    // do some common stuff
}
```

*Note* - **the language does not use short circuit evaluation**:

```
handler_1() || handler_2() || handler_3()
```

Would execute always all three handlers before checking the return values. I do not want that.

Available structures: SWITCH, GOTO, LABEL, FOR, WHILE, DO-WHILE, IF_ELSEIF_ELSE. It's also possible to make local variables.

Any ideas how to rewrite this code without using GOTO?

Comment: Don't tag this C if it's not C.

Comment: Then suggest some better tag. It is C syntax, and any C approach would work for me.

Comment: Better tag would be no tag than a wrong tag.

Comment: @meagar now I don't get syntax highlighting and no views. I'm adding the tag back.

Comment: Don't do the `do { ... } while(0)` abomination. It is worse than using `goto`, because it is an obfuscated way of writing exactly the same spaghetti code. The right response to your question is Quick19's answer.

Comment: "and any C approach would work for me." that's not true, as you've clearly demonstrated. The C approach would be to rely on operator short-circuiting.

Comment: "The right response to your question is Quick19's answer. " -- No, the right response is my answer. Quick19's response violates the explicit requirements in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend using a similar syntax to what you often see in the linux kernel.

```
func() {
    if (!handler_1())
        goto fail;
    if (!handler_2())
        goto fail;
    if (!handler_3())
        goto fail;

    print("success");
    return 0;

fail:
    print("failure");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: But then I still have a goto :(

Comment: And this is a perfectly reasonable use for goto.

Comment: Alright, I'll go this way. It's by far the cleanest.

Comment: oh, but.. the functionality is different. I need a "DONE" part that's executed after both success and fail. Another goto?

Comment: That starts to make it messy. If it makes sense with what the code is doing, I'd probably say keep this as one function, and then wrap it in a function that does the logic that always runs.

Answer (score 6):

here's one variant

```
func() {
    int good = 0;

    if (handler_1()) 
        good = 1;
    else if (handler_2()) 
        good = 1;
    else if (handler_3()) 
        good = 1

    if (good) {
       print("GOOD");
    } else {  
       print("BAD");
    }

    print("DONE");
    // do some common stuff
}
```

Comment: This looks good. Just one thing, you can use default good = 1, empty statements in the ifs, and good = 0; in the last else. I think.

Comment: @Quentin that would be preferred, but the OP doesn't have a suitable || operator

Answer (score 4):

Compare this to some of the awful alternatives offered:

```
handle() {
    if (handler_1()) return true;
    if (handler_2()) return true;
    if (handler_3()) return true;
    return false;
}

func(){
    print(handle() ? "GOOD" : "BAD");
    print("DONE");
    /// do some common stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy, use a sub-function:

```
handler_any() {
    if(handler_1())
        return 1;
    if(handler_2())
        return 1;
    return handler_3();
}

func() {
    if (!handler_any()) {
        print("BAD");
    } else {
        print("GOOD");
    }
    print("DONE");
    // do some common stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func() {  
   if (handler_1() || handler_2() || handler_3())  
     print("GOOD");   
else  print("BAD");
print("DONE");
    // do some common stuff
}
```

I didnt try the code above, but i believe it works. Dont forget to check if this is what you really want your program to do, because maybe I've got the idea wrong.

Btw, i hope i help you, and im sorry about my bad english. Good luck!

Comment: This would be OK in regular C, but here all functions in expression are evaluated first, and after that the expression is checked - so all handlers would be called each time. They are quite slow and call is expensive, so I'd rather avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
if (handler_1()) goto good;
if (handler_2()) goto good;
if (handler_3()) goto good;

bad:
    print("BAD");
    goto done;
good:
    print("GOOD");
    goto done;
```

to something like

```
bool good = true;
if (!handler_1()) {
  if (!handler_2()) {
    if (!handler_3()) {
      good = false;
    }
  }
}
if (good) {
  printf("Good");
} else {
  printf("Bad");
}
printf("Done");
```

Comment: Adding flag variables just makes the code confusing.  Gotos are just fine.

Comment: so you want to make fhe code less readable just so that you can call a goto something else. That is one horrible idea

Comment: @IraBaxter Edsger Dijkstra might disagree with you (I agree that it's not unreasonable here), but OP specifically asked for a method without goto or label.

Comment: @camelccc Why is answering OP's question something that I *want*?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: You know Dijkstra published that when structured programming just got started? It was not against the occasional `goto`, but against everywhere and always using `goto`. Also, I don't think he ever preached **convoluted coding for dogmatic avoidance of `goto` 101**.

Comment: @Deduplicator I said *might*, also it's what OP *asked* for. Finally, JWZ isn't totally against regular expressions; despite [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
"I know, I'll use regular expressions."  Now they have two problems.*](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: good = handler1() || handler2() || handler3(); is faster than if-branching.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Read OP's **note** in the question; *the language does not use short circuit evaluation*.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea "is faster than if-branching" -- the compiler generates branches for both.

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag variable is_good to indicate:

```
func() {
    int is_good = 0;

    if (handler_1()) is_good = 1;
    else if (handler_2()) is_good = 1;
    else if (handler_3()) is_good = 1;

    if (is_good == 1) 
    {print("BAD");}
    else
    {print("GOOD");}


    print("DONE");
    // do some common stuff
}
```

Comment: Then the handlers are all executed, always.

Answer (score 0):

This code without gotos and without any flags, will work fine

```
func() {
        if (!handler_1()) {
                if (!handler_2()) {
                        if (!handler_3()) {
                                print("BAD");
                        }
                        else {
                                print("GOOD");
                        }
                }
                else {
                        print("GOOD");
                }
        }
        else {
                print("GOOD");
        }

        print("DONE");
        // do some common stuff
}
```